# "because a mistake can be very pricey with chargebacks that are issues clients may have"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> You need to be a good developer yourself to have it communicate properly and not have any mistakes in there because a mistake can be very pricey with chargebacks that are issues clients may have. ([source](https://youtu.be/eyHsni17F_Q?t=199))

I'm not sure if I correctly understand it.
I believe this phrase means that issues are resulting in chargebacks?
Because customers have issues, they ask for chargebacks. Am I understand it correctly? (The person who use this phrase I think isn't a native speaker either)

Comment: Please post the complete sentence, and a link to the source. What you have posted is an incoherent fragment.

Comment: The presenter in the video was talking very fast and I'm not sure exactly what he said.  He might have said something like "because a mistake can be very pricey with chargebacks or other issues clients may have"

Comment: Hi Ocie. I thought the same, but I reduce speed to 0.25 listen this dozens time, and honestly still  think he said exactly this( of course I can be wrong. Just stuck at this and it's driving me crazy)

Comment: I'm definitely hearing "that are", not "or" in that part of the speech.

Comment: questions are something I may have. Same structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When written, the sentence is not well-formed.  When heard in your linked video, it is slightly clearer (but maybe because I have worked in software development, which is the subject of the video).

However, it is still a very awkward construction, and you shouldn't use it as an example of good English.

In the video, the speaker is describing how to implement communications with a third-party financial programming interface.

In the quoted part, he is effectively combining two statements:

1. He is *warning* that implementation mistakes are costly to rectify (e.g. because work needs to be redone, or because money incorrectly transferred is not easy to recover) — *a mistake can be very pricey*
2. He is *providing an example* of a common issue that can occur, which may cause your end-users to request the further support — *chargebacks that<sub>[sic]</sub> are issues clients may have*

It is ultimately a warning that writing code that works with money is *hard*, and that you need to be thorough (i.e. a "good developer") to make sure that you do it correctly.

For reference, the term, *chargeback*, is an industry term which is used to describe when a purchaser requests a refund for money they have paid via credit card.  The credit card company often charges a fee to the retailer (not the purchaser), when the refund is processed.

Additionally, it is common for software developers to refer to the people who *commission* the developed work as the *client*, rather than the people using the developed work (often distinguished as the *end-user*).

There is also an awkward distinction in software, that a *client* can also be the *piece of software* that specifically invokes the methods of the third-party programming interface (where those methods are provided by the *server*).

I am fairly certain that, in the quoted part, the term *client* refers to the people/organisation who commissioned the implementation.

Comment: Noted. So in the end it was me who didn't understand it correctly. Chargebacks are one of the issues customers can have not a result of customer issues. Thank you for clarifying it!

Comment: @MaciejWakowski :: I have added some context around *chargeback* and *client*.

Comment: Yes this greatly helped.  Chargebacks by definition deceive me(I thought they are initialized by banks, not customers that is why I was thinking about the second option as more probable). Thank you for clarifying it!

Answer (score 0):

The speaker in that video is not speaking English very well. I believe the meaning he intended was
"You need to be a good developer yourself to have it [your app] communicate properly and [you need]  not [to] have any mistakes in there [,] because a mistake can be very pricey [,] with chargebacks.  That is an issue clients may have."

You should not take this speaker's use of English as an example.

(I will add that I listened to some other parts of the  video, and they were bad too.)

Comment: Noted. I wasn't sure if chargebacks are just one of many issues that can arise or are the results of issues (I was more inclined to the second option though). Now it is clear. Thank you Jack.

Comment: Chargebacks can also be financial penalties that the agreement may provide for if the development team delivers a faulty product to the production team, for example.

Comment: I hear "You need to have a good developer or be a good developer yourself to... and [to/in order to] not have any mistakes in there, because a mistake can be very pricey, with chargebacks and other issues that clients may have." It is intelligible English. Also I thought he mistakenly said "to have it [the app] communicate properly" but possibly meant to say "to have it [the data, the details of the app etc.] **communicated** properly" because you don't want mistakes. But which one is intended is unclear in the context and I am not going to watch any more to deduce the meaning.